# How to reselect record with peewee

Tags: python, peewee

I try to update all properties of Peewee model object from database.

It is like that :

```
row = OauthReplyThread.get(thread_id=1)
time.sleep(60)
row.updateFromDatabase()
```

Is there any method like `row.updateFromDatabase()` in peewee?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No but you can add one:

```
def refresh(self):
    return type(self).get(self._pk_expr())
```

Comment: Your code does not update the object, it creates a new one.